# Orchard CMS 1.4: Adding javascript to specific content, eg, pages

Tags: orchardcms

Lets say I want to add an image gallery to a page using the lightbox jquery plugin.

Question:

How do I add the lightbox script?  Of course, I could add it to the layout.cshtml file for my theme, but then every page requires the lightbox script even if it doesn't use it.

And then I need to add the following script to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#photoGallery a').lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });

        });

</script>
```

Again, I could add it to the layout.cshtml file, but it would be better just to add it to the page.  OK, so I could create a layer for that page and add an html widget to a footer zone, but surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of the many image gallery modules that are available on the module gallery and be done with it. But if you want to do it manually, then I'm afraid you will have to do it manually, yes ;) But even using a special layer and widget seems convoluted: if you are going to go down that route, why don't you just put that script inside of the page markup (from the editor)?

Comment: OK, thanks, I will look at the modules gallery.  But what if I want a script in the <head> tag of a page?  I can't set a zone in the head tag to target, so is there another way?

Comment: In essence, this time was fine cos there is a ready made module to solve my issue.  But what about any other issue I may have with needing to use JS in my pages?

Comment: using(Script.Head()) { ...put your script tag here... }

Comment: That was the answer I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only load a script based on the presence of an element or set of elements I would do this:

```
function LazyLoadScripts() {
    if ($('#photogallery').length > 0) {
        $('<script src="path-to-script" type="text/javascript"></script>').appendTo('body');
        window.setTimeout("$('#photoGallery a').lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });", 1);
    }
    /* load any other scripts here in the same way */
}
$(document).ready(function() { LazyLoadScripts(); });
```

Now you can either insert that into your layout OR if you're code inclined you could create a new driver for the BodyPart and insert this script with a new shape. You'll also need to place that shape into either the head or the tail zone.